# document.querySelecterAll is not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple react app. I am trying to render a `JSX` element with some labels in it. And I am trying to run `javascript` code on click on particular `querySelectorAll` **"label"** but it is not working when I click on any label present in page. I am new in React.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const options = document.querySelectorAll("label");

        for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          options[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log(i)
         });
        }

        return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="1" className="div-down">
                <span>HTML</span>
            </label>

            <label htmlFor="2" className="div-down">
                <span>JavaScript</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        )
    }
}


export default App;
```

When I run the above code then it is showing nothing.

I have also tried putting `javascript` code in `.js` file and importing it but it is still not working. I have also tried by putting `javascript` code in `index.html` file but still not worked

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You Very much

Comment: The elements do not exist in the DOM until they're rendered, which only occurs after the `render` method finishes. While you could wait with `componentDidMount`, a better approach would be to avoid native DOM methods like `querySelectorAll` entirely and work within the React ecosystem instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As an option you could move the component to functional one and use `useEffect` there

```
const App = () => {

        useEffect(() => {
          const options = document.querySelectorAll("label");
          for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          options[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log(i)
          });
        }
        }, []);

        

        return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="1" className="div-down">
                <span>HTML</span>
            </label>

            <label htmlFor="2" className="div-down">
                <span>JavaScript</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        )
    
}
```

It will do most likely.

Comment: does `useEffect` even work in class based components?

Comment: Nicely noted. I don't expect to see class-based components nowadays so didn't even look for it : )

Comment: @IgorLoskutov, It is saying `'options' is not defined`